# The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). "firebase-messaging-sw"

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

So i'm quite new to reactJs and never had any prior knowledge of any other language apart from C, i've been using react with express, nodeJS, and mongo for about 3 months now. I've set up firebase on my PWA and i've generated a token to send messages, however I can't register my 'firebase-messaging-sw.js' file with serviceWorker to allow me to use importScripts.

This is currently what I have written in my index.html file :

```
<script>
    if('serviceWorker' in navigator) { 
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('../firebase-messaging-sw.js')
        .then(function(registration) {
         console.log("Service Worker Registered");
        messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);  
          }); 
          }
</script>
```

I keep getting the error
"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')."

I can't make much sense of the error and everything I see online doesn't help :/.

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Do you have your express routes setup properly to serve your js script? I.E. you arent accidently serving your index or other html file when a request for your js files comes in

Comment: @PatrickEvans Hey! thank you so much for your response. I'm not entirely sure how to check my express routes. But i would assume so, i read somewhere that useServiceWorker is deprecated. Do you know of any alternatives?